# Create sub domain on different server in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, webforms

I want to create sub-domain in asp.net. On local IIS server it is working fine and code generates a new website. The problem is, I want to create websites on Server(another pc).The following code generates website on local IIS server. Here is my code. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
 private void createDomain(string domainName, string subDomainName)
        {
            try
            {
                ServerManager serverMgr = new ServerManager();
                string strWebsitename = subDomainName+"." +domainName ; // abc
                string strApplicationPool = "ASP.NET v4.0";  // set your deafultpool :4.0 in IIS
                string strhostname = subDomainName + "." + domainName; //abc.com
                string stripaddress = "192.168.10.25";// ip address
                string bindinginfo = stripaddress + ":80:" + strhostname;

                //check if website name already exists in IIS
                Boolean bWebsite = IsWebsiteExists(strWebsitename);
            
                if (!bWebsite)
                {
                    Site mySite = serverMgr.Sites.Add(strWebsitename.ToString(), "http", bindinginfo, "C:\\inetpub\\TestApp");
                    mySite.ApplicationDefaults.ApplicationPoolName = strApplicationPool;
                    mySite.TraceFailedRequestsLogging.Enabled = true;
                    mySite.TraceFailedRequestsLogging.Directory = "C:\\inetpub\\Logging";
                    serverMgr.CommitChanges();
                   
                }
                else
                {
                    
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ae)
            {
                Response.Redirect(ae.Message);
            }
        }
```

I want to create website like following picture in Server (another pc with IIS server)
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPpbG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell to server manager that you want to manage a remote machine:

```
ServerManager serverMgr = ServerManager.OpenRemote("machineName");
```

Also, if running under VS, beware of run it as Administrator.

Comment: Thanks, "machineName" will be an ip address of that server?

Comment: @InamUrRehman It seems that you need to use remote server name, not ip, as per documentation. Also, beware that you need to use a domain admin account for this.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager.openremote(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks @Oscar It is helpful for me.